# CSS :nth-child in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make some nth-child to work in ie8, this is example of rule i have, but as you may know it will not work in i8

```
th:nth-child(n+3) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But it has to work in IE8, i know in ie8 that first-child is supported, and easy can use like

```
td:first-child + td + td
```

But I don't know how to do when i have `(n+)`, does anybody knows how to accomplish this to work in ie8 but from as you may see third child?

Comment: define the class for them...

Comment: You could either try applying a class to every n+3rd item on the server side. Or you could do it using JavaScript. With CSS alone it is going to be hard.

Comment: I need css to do this

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed number of elements, you can define them manually, it's the only way using pure CSS without classes in your HTML markup.

```
td:first-child,
td:first-child + td + td + td,
td:first-child + td + td + td + td + td + td,
td:first-child + td + td + td + td + td + td + td + td + td {...}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63aw8yhv/2/